# How can I remove the "Search more... " option from a many to many field?

Tags: xml, many-to-many, odoo, odoo-11

If I show the many2many field with the widget `many2many_tags` the option "Search more..." appears in the drop-down menu. How can I avoid it?

```xml
<field name="groups_id" 
       widget="many2many_tags"  
       create="0" 
       options="{'no_create_edit': True,'no_quick_create':True,'no_create':True,'no_open':True}"/>
```

[image]

Is there a way to remove the "Search more... " option?

Answer (score 4):

You have some options:

- You can use the `widget="selection"` if it is a `many2one` field.
- You can install the module [**web_m2x_options**](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/web_m2x_options/), but you should write a limit in this case like this:

  ```xml
  <field name="groups_id" 
         options="{'limit': 10, 'create': false, 'create_edit': false}"/>
  ```
- As an alternative, you can also use the `many2many_checkboxes` widget:

  ```xml
  <field name="location_ids" widget="many2many_checkboxes"/>
  ```

  You can even show the checkboxes in two columns as I have written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50545053/4891717) (solution for Odoo 10 and 11)

Comment: Thank you for your help but there is now change more search is always there it's really a problem my be because i'm using Odoo 9?!!

Comment: Did you try the module? You are right, the module is not migrated to Odoo 9. Another reason can be that is a many2many field. Did you try with the widget selection?

Comment: widget selection works fine with many2one but manay2many no because it select only one element  but is used widget="many2many_checkboxes" for now but the problem is when you need with a big set of items you see !! but i think i can work the write acces to remove the write to create for the user

Comment: @Sami what version of Odoo are you using? The module of the second solution was migrated to Odoo 10. Doesn't it work either for many2many fields?

Comment: Using odoo11 and I need to use `many2many_tags` because i need a select list dropdown with multiple selection

Comment: @Sami OK, the module wasn't migrated to Odoo 11 yet.