# How to organize many2many checkboxes in lines (rows) rather than columns?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view, odoo-11

I am creating one module where I have a `Many2many` field and I would like to convert it into a checkbox group. I have written this in my XML view to achieving it

```
<field name="location_ids" widget="many2many_checkboxes"/>
```

But the field is shown all the options in a long column. I would like to show the options in multiple rows as in the following image:

Comment: I have edited your question for better explanation, but I do not know if you wanted to say what I have written or the opposite. Could you check it?

Comment: I am afraid you would need to inherit some JavaScript code and change it

Comment: @ChesuCRI It looks like res.user -> Technical Settings there is all row and 2 column type of checkbox but how to do it in the many2many checkbox field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found a good approach for you.

### Research

First I have search the original template which is rendered with the widget `many2many_checkboxes`. This one:

```
<t t-name="FieldMany2ManyCheckBoxes">
    <div t-foreach="widget.get('records')" t-as="record">
        <div class="o_checkbox">
            <input t-if="widget.get('value').indexOf(record[0]) !== -1" type="checkbox" t-att-data-record-id="JSON.stringify(record[0])" checked="checked"/>
            <input t-if="widget.get('value').indexOf(record[0]) === -1" type="checkbox" t-att-data-record-id="JSON.stringify(record[0])"/>
            <span/>
        </div>
        <label class="o_form_label"><t t-esc="record[1]"/></label>
    </div>
</t>
```

### Template

So, I have copied the result html code of the `group` structure and I have combined it with the template of the widget.

You need to create a xml file with this content and add it to your `__manifes__.py` file:

```
'qweb': ['static/src/xml/many2many_checkboxes.xml', ]
```

**The code of `many2many_checkboxes.xml`**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="FieldMany2ManyCheckBoxes">
        <t t-jquery="div:first" t-operation="replace">
            <div class="o_group">    
                <table class="o_group o_inner_group o_group_col_6">
                    <tbody>
                        <t t-foreach="widget.m2mValues" t-as="record">
                            <t t-if="record_parity == 'odd'">
                                <t t-set="id_for_label" t-value="'o_many2many_checkbox_' + _.uniqueId()"/>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="1" class="o_td_label">
                                        <label t-att-for="id_for_label" class="o_form_label"><t t-esc="record[1]"/></label>
                                    </td>

                                    <td colspan="1" style="width: 50%;">
                                        <div class="o_checkbox o_form_field_boolean o_form_field">
                                            <div class="o_checkbox">
                                                <input type="checkbox" t-att-id="id_for_label" t-att-data-record-id="JSON.stringify(record[0])"/>
                                                <span/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </t>
                        </t>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <table class="o_group o_inner_group o_group_col_6 pull-right">
                    <tbody>
                        <t t-foreach="widget.m2mValues" t-as="record">
                            <t t-if="record_parity == 'even'">
                                <t t-set="id_for_label" t-value="'o_many2many_checkbox_' + _.uniqueId()"/>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="1" class="o_td_label">
                                        <label t-att-for="id_for_label" class="o_form_label"><t t-esc="record[1]"/></label>
                                    </td>

                                    <td colspan="1" style="width: 50%;">
                                        <div class="o_checkbox o_form_field_boolean o_form_field">
                                            <div class="o_checkbox">
                                                <input type="checkbox" t-att-id="id_for_label" t-att-data-record-id="JSON.stringify(record[0])"/>
                                                <span/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </t>
                        </t>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

### Form

Finally add the field in your form. But without `group` elements since we are already adding the `group` html elements on the template above. You need to add the this attribute `style="display: block;"` in order to keep the position in the grid right.

```xml
<separator string="Field name" />
<field name="test_many2many_checkboxes"
        widget="many2many_checkboxes"
        nolabel="1"
        style="display: block;" />
```

Let me know if this works for you. I have tested with my Odoo 11 instance and it works fine. This is the result with two columns. If you want three columns you will need to adapt the template:

[image: result]

### Possible Alternative

I have checked how Odoo developers have done the table on the "Technical Settings". They are creating one single table instead of two as I do. So maybe there is a better way to do it because I need to loop over all the records twice to build the two tables.

Anyway you are free to improve my code. I only wanted to guide you to the solution. Maybe you can group the records in threes to build the rows.

### Odoo 10

The template changes a little bit for the version 10, so you need to use this template instead:

```xml
<t t-extend="FieldMany2ManyCheckBoxes">
    <t t-jquery="div:first" t-operation="replace">
        <div class="o_group">    
            <table class="o_group o_inner_group o_group_col_6">
                <tbody>
                    <t t-foreach="widget.get('records')" t-as="record">
                        <t t-if="record_parity == 'odd'">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="1" class="o_td_label">
                                    <label for="o_field_input_28" class="o_form_label" data-original-title="" title="">
                                        <span t-esc="record[1]"/>
                                    </label>
                                </td>

                                <td colspan="1" style="width: 50%;">
                                    <div class="o_checkbox o_form_field_boolean o_form_field">
                                        <div class="o_checkbox">
                                            <input t-if="widget.get('value').indexOf(record[0]) !== -1" type="checkbox" t-att-data-record-id="JSON.stringify(record[0])" checked="checked"/>
                                            <input t-if="widget.get('value').indexOf(record[0]) === -1" type="checkbox" t-att-data-record-id="JSON.stringify(record[0])"/>
                                            <span/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </t>
                    </t>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <table class="o_group o_inner_group o_group_col_6 pull-right">
                <tbody>
                    <t t-foreach="widget.get('records')" t-as="record">
                        <t t-if="record_parity == 'even'">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="1" class="o_td_label">
                                    <label for="o_field_input_28" class="o_form_label" data-original-title="" title="">
                                        <span t-esc="record[1]"/>
                                    </label>
                                </td>

                                <td colspan="1" style="width: 50%;">
                                    <div class="o_checkbox o_form_field_boolean o_form_field">
                                        <div class="o_checkbox">
                                            <input t-if="widget.get('value').indexOf(record[0]) !== -1" type="checkbox" t-att-data-record-id="JSON.stringify(record[0])" checked="checked"/>
                                            <input t-if="widget.get('value').indexOf(record[0]) === -1" type="checkbox" t-att-data-record-id="JSON.stringify(record[0])"/>
                                            <span/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </t>
                    </t>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </t>
</t>
```

Comment: Hello, how to change the 4 column?

Comment: @C Split all the records in two groups. First, show the first half in two columns as I show in my answer, then show the second half.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `widget="radio"` , then we can make it as per your need by giving `options="{'horizontal': true}"` . You can use widget radio on selection fields also. So the view will update like this.

code:

```
<field name="sale_pricelist_setting" class="oe_inline" widget="radio" options="{'horizontal': true}"/>
```

**Before:**
[image]

**After as horizontal:**
[image]

Comment: I saw your answer but it is not useful for me because I have Many2many fields and using checkbox so I can check multiple values at a time and If I use radio it is should be only one value selected at a time..

Comment: yes, Then you should update css as per your need. there is no other option. or extend the widget="many2many_checkboxes"

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve your result you need to add a custom css class on field as described below.

```
<field name="location_ids widget="many2many_checkboxes" class="your_new_class"/>
```

Create a new css file and add following css.

```
.your_new_class  > div {
    float:left;
}
```

**Explanation:**

If you define widget=many2many_checkboxes as per the framework it will create a div for each possible values in dom.

So as  a solution we need to create a new css class and apply it to field and add proper css properties for your desired result.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for answering but its not work for me to applying css about m2m field.

Comment: I am not getting you. May I know the reason why you can not apply css class on m2m field ?